# JQuery GET request on Sinatra always results in error

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, sinatra

I am using Sinatra to host a simple service.  This is my entire application:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/hello' do
  'Hello world!'
end
```

I then have a single html file in my `./public` directory that tries a GET request on my service:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("a").click(function(event) {
                $.get("/hello", function() { alert("first success"); })
                        .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
                        .error(function(jqXHR) { alert("error: " + jqXHR); });
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="">Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the link on my HTML page, I see the following in my server log:

> 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0 - - [16/Feb/2011 10:37:42] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 200 12 0.0030
>   localhost - - [16/Feb/2011:10:37:42 CST] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 200 12
>   Referer -> /hello

Which seems good, but no matter how I try to tweak things I can only get the error callback to be invoked - never the success.

I have two questions:
1) What am I doing wrong?
2) How should I go about debugging problems like this?  The object passed to the error callback is just an Object, and I have no way of getting info about the error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During my testing I was having problems with the click code for the link not having a `return false;`, so the page would keep reloading. With Firebug, I got the error `uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.getAllResponseHeaders]" nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)" location: "JS frame :: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js :: anonymous :: line 16" data: no]`.

When I changed the link from `<a href="">Link</a>` to `<a>Link</a>`, the code worked (I got both first and second success messages). Also, If I left the link as-is and added `return false;` to the end of the `$("a").click` code, the code also worked.

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for making it sound like I'm not stupid :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Error: uncaught exception: 
[Exception... "prompt aborted by user"  nsresult: "0x80040111 
(NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: 
"JS frame :: resource:///components/nsPrompter.js :: openTabPrompt :: line 457"  data: no]
```

I got this error when I had both onclick event and a live href url attached to the anchor tag.